# The Sorceress and the Cygnet: what happened?

Tags: patricia-mckillip

Sometimes, I find Patricia McKillip’s writing so dense that I can’t quite follow the action. The climactic fight at the end of ‘The Sorceress and the Cygnet’ is an example. How did the fight between the Cygnet and the other semi-mythical personages change to some sort of compromise outcome?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the idea is that the whole scheme orchestrated by the semi-mythical personages, as you call them, was an attempt to wake up Nix Ro and prevent her from becoming a danger to all of Ro Holding, and perhaps especially to the assorted other subordinate holdings that the personages embody or represent.

Nyx has been living off by herself in the swamps, focused entirely on magic and power and becoming less and less human and more and more amoral and, well, heartless (witness her casual dismemberment of birds, or the way Corleu perceives her initially: "She studied him curiously, as if he were a rare tree frog that maybe she could use in her fire."). Since she is a powerful sorceress *and* the heir to Ro Holding, if she continued down the path she was on, she could one day be a danger to everyone, not just the local birds and frogs.

So when, in the climactic fight, she abandons her quest for power and throws herself across the chamber to save Corleu (someone who isn't even part of her family), she demonstrates that she has recovered (at least partly) some of her humanity and her heart. So the Gold King and his compatriots have succeeded, and the conflict can end.

That's why, I think, she tells her mother afterwards, "In my house in the swamp, there was a room full of mirrors. I looked into them. I never saw what they reflected. Their reflections seemed to have followed me here, forced me to look again."